# Get a serial input to print correctly formatted to a list

Tags: python, list, arduino, serial-port

I need to get a serial input to put its data into a list. At the moment I am using

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0) #config serial port to read

GRAPH=[0]

t_end = time.time() + 10
while time.time() < t_end:
    try:
        outp=ser.readline() #reads serial port
        GRAPH+=((outp.decode('utf-8'))) #decodes and prints data
        print((outp.decode('utf-8')))
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Which is printing the data like follows:

```
8.46,

8.76,

9.02,

9.08,

9.43,

9.32,
```

However in the GRAPH list it is coming up as follows:

```
'8', '.', '4', '6', ',', '8', '.', '7', '6', ',', '9', '.', '0', '2', ',', '9', '.', '0', '8', ',', '9', '.', '4', '3', ',', '9', '.', '3', '2', ','
```

How can I get it to put it into the list like the values that are being printed?

Comment: try `GRAPH.append(float(outp.decode('utf-8')[:-1]))` instead of `GRAPH+=((outp.decode('utf-8')))`

Comment: That worked! I did however need to input it as GRAPH.append(outp.decode('utf-8')[:-1]) because it didn't seem to like floating.

Answer (score 0):

As Nullman stated above, I needed to use:

```
GRAPH.append(outp.decode('utf-8')[:-1])
```

to get it to work.